# where condition is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

There are two tables `department` and `user`. `department` table have `name` and `id` entities and `user` table have `name`, `id` and `department_id`. `department_id` have some `null` values and the code I wrote is `shoes` only `null` values. In `department` table, `sales` has `ID = 2` and in `user`, table Staff has `department_id = 2`...

So I want when I select sales there will be the only staff shoes.

TestController:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Departments;
use App\Users;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function prodfunct(){
        $department = Departments::all(); // Get data from table

        return view('productlist', compact('department')); // Send data to the view
    }

    public function findUsersName(Request $request){
        $data = Users::select('name', 'department_id')
            ->where('department_id', $request->id)
            ->take(100)
            ->get();
        
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: User table]

[image: Department table]

`Product.blade.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

    <h1>Dependant Drop Down with ajax</h1>

    <span>Product Category: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="productcategory" id="department_id">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
        @foreach($department as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <span>Product Name: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="name">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Product Name</option>
    </select>
</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.productcategory',function(){
            // console.log("hmm it's change");

            var cat_id=$(this).val();
            //console.log(cat_id);
            var div=$(this).parent();

            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
                data:{'department_id':cat_id},
            
                success:function(data){
                    //console.log('success');

                    console.log(data);

                    console.log(data.length);
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose product</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].department_id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
                    
                   }

                   div.find('.name').html(" ");
                   div.find('.name').append(op);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are saying is that when you select a particular category you want every users under that category to be displayed. If that's the case then you need to create a relationship between the two models. The Department model will have an eloquent relationship of have many USer models and User model will have a relationship of BelongsTo Department model. Then in your view you create a foreach loop to show every user in a department by writing cat->user->name and that will print all users under that category. If this isnt what you are looking for expatiate more on your issue and possibly send a github repo link.